# class not retrieving information from another class

Tags: java

Grocery_shop

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

/**
   Grocery shop class

*/

public class Grocery_shop extends JFrame
{

   private quantitypanel qty; // A panel for quantity
   private Grocery_items items;       // A panel for routine charge checkboxes
   private JPanel buttonPanel; // A panel for the buttons
   private JButton calcButton;         // Calculates everything
   private JButton exitButton;         // Exits the application

   private invoiceClass invoice;

   /**
      Constructor
   */

   public Grocery_shop()
   {
      // Display a title.
      setTitle("Victor's Grocery Shop");

      // Specify what happens when the close button is clicked.
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


 // Create a NonRoutinePanel object.
      qty = new quantitypanel();
    //  qty.setBackground(Color.white);

      // Create a RoutinePanel object.
      items = new Grocery_items( qty );



      // Build the panel that contains the buttons.
      buildButtonPanel();

      // Add the panels to the content pane.
      add(items, BorderLayout.WEST);
      add(qty, BorderLayout.EAST);
      add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      // Pack and display the window.
      pack();
      setVisible(true);
   }

   /**
      The buildButtonPanel method creates a panel containing
      buttons.
   */

   private void buildButtonPanel()
   {
      // Create a button to calculate the charges.
      calcButton = new JButton("Add Charges");

      // Add an action listener to the button.
      calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());

      // Create a button to exit the application.
      exitButton = new JButton("Exit");

      // Add an action listener to the button.
      exitButton.addActionListener(new ExitButtonListener());

      // Put the buttons in their own panel.
      buttonPanel = new JPanel();
      buttonPanel.add(calcButton);
      buttonPanel.add(exitButton);
   }

   /**
      CalcButtonListener is an action listener class for the
      calcButton component.
   */

   private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener
   {
      /**
         actionPerformed method
         @param e An ActionEvent object.
      */

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         double totalCharges; // Total charges

         // Create a DecimalFormat object to format output.
         DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

         // Calculate the total charges
         totalCharges = items.getCharges(); 
                 //+ nonRoutine.getCharges();

         // Display the message.
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total Charges: $" + 
                                             dollar.format(totalCharges));
         invoice = new invoiceClass();
         invoice.getClass();
      }
   } // End of inner class

   /**
      ExitButtonListener is an action listener class for the
      exitButton component.
   */

   private class ExitButtonListener implements ActionListener
   {
      /**
         actionPerformed method
         @param e An ActionEvent object.
      */

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {

         System.exit(0);
      }
   } // End of inner class

   /**
      The main method creates an instance of the JoesAutomotive
      class, causing it to display its window.
   */

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Grocery_shop grocery = new Grocery_shop();
   }
}
```

Grocery_items

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

/**
   RoutinePanel class

*/

public class Grocery_items extends JPanel
{
   // Named constants for charges
   private final double Baked_Beans  = 0.35;
   private final double Cornflakes = 1.75;
   private final double Sugar = 0.75;
   private final double Tea_Bags = 1.15;
   private final double Instant_Coffee = 2.50;
   private final double Bread = 1.25;
   private final double Sausage = 1.30;
   private final double Eggs = 0.75;
   private final double Milk = 0.65;
   private final double Potatoes = 2.00;

   private quantitypanel qty; // A panel for quantity


   private JCheckBox baked_beans_box;     // Check box for baked_beans
   private JCheckBox CornflakesBox;       // Check box for cornflakes
   private JCheckBox SugarBox; // Check box for sugar box
   private JCheckBox Tea_Bags_Box;    // Check box for tea bag
   private JCheckBox Instant_Coffee_Box;    // Check box for Instant_Coffee_Box
   private JCheckBox Bread_Box;       // Check box for bread box
   private JCheckBox SausageBox;  // Check box for sausage box
   private JCheckBox eggbox;  // Check box for egg box
   private JCheckBox milkbox;  // Check box for milk
   private JCheckBox potatoesbox;  // Check box for potatoes

 //  private JTextField baked_beans_JT; 
   /**
      Constructor
   */

   public Grocery_items(quantitypanel qty)
   {
    this.qty = qty;
      DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");


      // Create the check boxes.
      baked_beans_box = new JCheckBox("Baked_Beans ($" +
                                dollar.format(Baked_Beans) + ")");



      CornflakesBox = new JCheckBox("Cornflakes ($" +
                              dollar.format(Cornflakes) + ")");
      SugarBox = new JCheckBox("Sugar ($" + 
                                    dollar.format(Sugar) + ")");
      Tea_Bags_Box = new JCheckBox("Tea Bags ($" + 
                                 dollar.format(Tea_Bags) + ")");
      Instant_Coffee_Box = new JCheckBox("Instant Coffee_Box ($" + 
                                 dollar.format(Instant_Coffee) + ")");
      Bread_Box = new JCheckBox("Bread Box ($" + 
                              dollar.format(Bread) + ")");
      SausageBox = new JCheckBox("Suasages ($" + 
                                   dollar.format(Sausage) + ")");
      eggbox = new JCheckBox("Eggs ($" + 
              dollar.format(Eggs) + ")");

      milkbox = new JCheckBox("Milk ($" + 
              dollar.format(Milk) + ")");
      potatoesbox = new JCheckBox("Potatoes ($" + 
              dollar.format(Potatoes) + ")");

      // Create a GridLayout manager.
      setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 1));

      // Create a border.
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Grocery Items"));

      // Add the check boxes to this panel.
      add(baked_beans_box);
      add(CornflakesBox);
      add(SugarBox);
      add(Tea_Bags_Box);
      add(Instant_Coffee_Box);
      add(Bread_Box);
      add(SausageBox);
      add(eggbox);
      add(milkbox);
      add(potatoesbox);

   }



   /**
      The getCharges method calculates the routine charges.
      @return The amount of routine charges.
   */

   public double getCharges()
   {
      double charges = 0;

      if (baked_beans_box.isSelected())
         charges += Baked_Beans * qty.getBeanqty();
      if (CornflakesBox.isSelected())
         charges += Cornflakes;
      if (SugarBox.isSelected())
         charges += Sugar;
      if (Tea_Bags_Box.isSelected())
         charges += Tea_Bags;
      if (Instant_Coffee_Box.isSelected())
         charges += Instant_Coffee;
      if (Bread_Box.isSelected())
         charges += Bread;
      if (SausageBox.isSelected())
         charges += Sausage;
      if (eggbox.isSelected())
          charges += Eggs;
      if (milkbox.isSelected())
          charges += Milk;
      if (potatoesbox.isSelected())
          charges += Potatoes;



      return charges;
   }
}
```

quantitypanel

```
    //import java.awt.LayoutManager;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    //import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
    //import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;


    public class quantitypanel extends JPanel {
         private JTextField baked_beans_JT;     // JTextField box for baked_beans
           private JTextField Cornflakes_JT;       // JTextField box for cornflakes
           private JTextField Sugar_JT; // JTextField box for sugar box
           private JTextField Tea_Bags_JT;    // JTextField box for tea bag
           private JTextField Instant_Coffee_JT;    // JTextField box for Instant_Coffee_Box
           private JTextField Bread_JT;       // JTextField box for bread box
           private JTextField Sausage_JT;  // JTextField box for sausage box
           private JTextField egg_JT;  // JTextField box for egg box
           private JTextField milk_JT;  // JTextField box for milk
           private JTextField potatoes_JT;  // JTextField box for potatoes


           public quantitypanel()
           {

               //create JTextField.
               baked_beans_JT = new JTextField(5);
               Cornflakes_JT = new JTextField(5);
               Sugar_JT = new JTextField(5);
               Tea_Bags_JT = new JTextField(5);
               Instant_Coffee_JT = new JTextField(5);
               Bread_JT = new JTextField(5);
               Sausage_JT = new JTextField(5);
               egg_JT = new JTextField(5);
               milk_JT = new JTextField(5);
               potatoes_JT = new JTextField(5);


               //initialize text field to 0
               baked_beans_JT.setText("0");
               Cornflakes_JT.setText("0");
               Sugar_JT.setText("0");
               Tea_Bags_JT.setText("0");
               Instant_Coffee_JT.setText("0");
               Bread_JT.setText("0");
               Sausage_JT.setText("0");
               egg_JT.setText("0");
               milk_JT.setText("0");
               potatoes_JT.setText("0");




               //set Layout manager
               setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 1));

               //create border and panel title

              setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Amount"));

              //add text fields to the panel.
              add(baked_beans_JT);
              add(Cornflakes_JT);
              add(Sugar_JT);
              add(Tea_Bags_JT);
              add(Instant_Coffee_JT);
              add(Bread_JT);
              add(Sausage_JT);
              add(egg_JT);
              add(milk_JT);
              add(potatoes_JT);


           }

           public double getBeanqty()
             {
                 try
           {
                 return Double.parseDouble(baked_beans_JT.getText());


           }

           catch(NumberFormatException ev){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "invalid");
           }
                return 0;

           }

    }



invoiceClass


import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class invoiceClass {
    private Grocery_items items;
    private quantitypanel qty; // A panel for quantity



    {
         double total; // Total charges

 DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");


 qty = new quantitypanel();

 items = new Grocery_items(qty);

         // Calculate the total charges

         double payment = 0.0;
         String input;
     input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "enter a your payment");
     payment = Double.parseDouble(input);
     total = payment - items.getCharges(); 
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "your change is: " + total);

}
}
```

Please with the code above, i'm trying to make a receipt for the program.

I want in this code `total = payment - items.getCharges();` for the system to get the total charges and subtract it from the number the user inputs. In this case the system is only recognising the payment.

Please help..

thanks

Comment: When you say that the system doesn't recognize items.getCharges(), what do you mean? Do you get a compile time error? What does it say?

Comment: I would also note that in Java, the naming convention for Classes are to do something like GroceryItems.java, QuantityPanel.java, GroceryShop.java.

Comment: for example if the value of the payment is 10. then the system prints only 10 in the JOptionpane. i want it to get the charges AND subtract it from the payment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that `items.getCharges()` returns 0 is that a new `invoiceClass` instance is created every time a `CalcButtonListener` `Action` occurs. This creates a new `Grocery_items` instance.

This, in turn, creates new GUI elements including checkboxes. These checkboxes are not the ones visible in the application as they have not been added. Now when you go to call `getCharges`, the selection state of the `JCheckBoxes` on the newly created `Grocery_items` will be `false` (default state of `JCheckBox`) so no charges will be added

```
public double getCharges() {
   double charges = 0;

if (baked_beans_box.isSelected()) // now false!
   charges += Baked_Beans * qty.getBeanqty(); 
if (...)
```

The solution, therefore, is not to create `Grocery_items` in `quantitypanel` but to use the original instance.

Aside: Use Java naming conventions have classes that start with *uppercase* such as `QuantityPanel`. Underscores are typically not used, e.g. `GroceryItems`

Comment: what do you mean by the original instance please.

Comment: The instance of `Grocery_items` created in the constructor of `Grocery_shop`